# In The Captain Is Dead Episode 2: Adrift, do all systems with any damage gain damage no matter where hostile aliens are?

Tags: the-captain-is-dead, the-captain-is-dead-adrift

The instuctions [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/download.thegamecrafter.com/1437540315/Rules.pdf) say

> At the start of any turn in which a hostile alien is present, add a damage token to any system that already has a damage token.

Does this mean if an alien is anywhere in the ship, that all systems with damage accrue damage, or only damaged systems in the same room that has an alien?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What that means is that if an alien is in a room with a system that is damaged such as engineering and the teleporter has damage then another damage token will be added to the teleporter. If the comm system also had damage to it but there are no aliens on the bridge then no damage tokens will be added to it when the aliens cause the teleporter to get another damage token. What is happening is that the aliens are just causing more damage in the area they currently are.